# Unable to test using dispatch Event for ionic-input

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a simple reactive form with input field.

HTML as follows

```
<ion-input type="string" formControlName="email" name="email" id="email"></ion-input>
```

Am trying to test the above along with my component.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.registrationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    email: [undefined, Validators.required],
    password: ['', Validators.required],
    confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required],
    countryCode: ['', Validators.required],
    mobileNumber: [null, Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]+'), Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(10)]
  });
}
```

Spec test below

```
describe('SignupPage', () => {
  let component: SignupPage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SignupPage>;
  let countryCodes: Countrycode[];
  let countryCodeService: CountrycodeService;
  let userService: UserService;
  let toastController: MockToastController;
  let debugElement: DebugElement;
  let emailElement: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SignupPage],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      imports: [TranslateModule.forRoot(), RouterTestingModule, IonicModule,
      NgxWebstorageModule.forRoot(), HttpClientTestingModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: ToastController, useClass: MockToastController }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SignupPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    countryCodeService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(CountrycodeService);
    toastController = TestBed.get(ToastController);
    userService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(UserService);
    debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    emailElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#email'));
    // set country codes data
    this.countryCodes = [{ id: 0, name: 'India', code: '+91' }, { id: 1, name: 'Indonesia', code: '+92' }];
  });

  it('should not unblur the register text on button if only email is filled rest all empty ', fakeAsync(() => {
    // Given
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().append('link', 'link;link');
    spyOn(countryCodeService, 'query').and.returnValue(of(
      new HttpResponse({
        body: this.countryCodes,
        headers
      })
    ))
    // When
    component.ngOnInit();
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    //Given
    const emailNativeElement = emailElement.nativeElement;
    emailNativeElement.value = 'abhinav@abhinav.com';
    console.log('EMAIL ELEMENT IS ------------ ' + emailElement.nativeElement.value);
    const inputEvent = new Event('input');
    emailNativeElement.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    console.log('----contrlls are ----'+ JSON.stringify(component.registrationForm.touched));
    console.log(' - the control value is ' + component.registrationForm.controls['email'].value);
    // then
    expect(component.registrationForm.controls['email'].hasError('required')).toBe(false);
  }));
```

The dispatchEvent does not update the component. However when I use a html input instead of ion-input the test works.

```
<input type="string" formControlName="email" name="email" id="email"/>
```

Test Passes for above HTML but not when I use ion-input

Anyone knows how to send dispatch event for ionic based tags

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work. The event type should be ionChange not input.

```
const inputEvent = new Event('input');
```

should be

```
const inputEvent = new Event('ionChange');
```